# How to resize a table to fit the page's width (without changing font size)

Tags: tables

How  to resize a table to fit the page's width (without changing font size)?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Types}  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Days} \\ \cline{2-5}
                     & Day 1   & Day 2 & Day 3 &  Day 4  \\ \hline 
             Type 1   & 12-06-08-07-09-08-18-32-48-101-108& 13-88-08-07-09-08-14-39-36-10 & 56-33-08-07-09-08-18-32-48&26-29-26\\ \hline 
             Type 2   & 01-07-10-22-55-07-100-32-48& 08-18-32-48-66-36-10 &26-29-26& 10-55-21\\ \hline 

\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

The table exceeds the width of the page:
[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: change `c` to `p{3cm}` or whatever width you need

Comment: Would fixing some column width be ok? If so, you can replace some of the `c` parameters in the columns definition with something like `p{3cm}`.

Answer (score 7):

Since you don't want to reduce the font size, it's necessary to introduce line breaks. You may want to use the `tabularx` package and its `tabularx` environment, modifying that package's `X` column type to centerset the contents of columns 2 through 5.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l|C|C|C|C @{}}
 \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Types} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Days} \\ 
 \cline{2-5}
     & Day 1  & Day 2 & Day 3 &  Day 4  \\ \hline
     Type 1   & 12-06-08-07-09-08-18-32-48-101-108& 13-88-08-07-09-08-14-39-36-10 & 56-33-08-07-09-08-18-32-48&26-29-26\\ \hline
     Type 2   & 01-07-10-22-55-07-100-32-48& 08-18-32-48-66-36-10 &26-29-26& 10-55-21\\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

PS If the strings "Type 1" and "Type 2" need to be centered vertically, just encase them in `\multirow{2}{*}{...}` statements.

---

*Addendum*: You may want to consider giving your table a more "open" or "airy" look. One way to do so would be to get rid of all vertical lines and use the macros of the `booktabs` package to get well-spaced horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lCCCC @{}}
 \toprule
 Types & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Days} \\
 \cmidrule(l){2-5}
     & Day 1  & Day 2 & Day 3 &  Day 4  \\
 \midrule
     Type 1   & 12-06-08-07-09-08-18-32-48-101-108& 13-88-08-07-09-08-14-39-36-10 & 56-33-08-07-09-08-18-32-48&26-29-26\\
 \addlinespace
     Type 2   & 01-07-10-22-55-07-100-32-48& 08-18-32-48-66-36-10 &26-29-26& 10-55-21\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.1cm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|M|M|M|M|}
\hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Types}  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Days} \\ \cline{2-5}
                     & Day 1   & Day 2 & Day 3 &  Day 4  \\ \hline
             Type 1   & 12-06-08-07-09-08-18-32-48-101-108& 13-88-08-07-09-08-14-39-36-10 & 56-33-08-07-09-08-18-32-48&26-29-26\\ \hline
             Type 2   & 01-07-10-22-55-07-100-32-48& 08-18-32-48-66-36-10 &26-29-26& 10-55-21\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to explain how you came up with the width of `3.1cm` for columns of type `M`. :-)

Comment: @Mico It is purely empirical. Try and eye ball :)